# sed, insert whitespace at the Nth position after a delimiter

Tags: bash, sed, delimiter

I am not very fluent using bash especially the sed command:
I am trying to use sed to insert another whitespace **at the 2nd position after each whitespace** in the following string:

```
Id_26300, 0404 0202 0202 0202
```

in order to obtain:

```
Id_26300, 04 04 02 02 02 02 02 02
```

and I need to do this in my whole text file from line 3 to the end:

```
FileName
InfoField A B C D
Id_26300, 04 04 02 02 02 02 02 02
Id_26301, 02 02 02 04 02 04 02 02
...
```

I tried to find a solution but could not... Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Not sure why this question has been closed seems focused enough. Perhaps try (GNU sed)  `sed -E '3,${:a;s/(, *([0-9]{2} )*[0-9]{2}\B)/\1 /;ta}' file` if the question is re-opened I will give an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! I would be curious of getting the explanation for this option. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the limited input:

`sed '3,$s/ ../& /g'`

From line 3 to the end of the file `3,$`, match a space followed by any 2 characters  `..`.  Use `&` to mean "what was matched" and add a space after it.  Use `g` to do repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you very much to you both! Both of these solutions work. I tick this as the accepted answer as it is a bit simpler :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '3,${:a;s/, *([0-9]{2} )*[0-9]{2}\B/& /;ta}' file
```

From the third line to the end of the file, match from the first field delimiter `,` , any number of spaces, zero or more collections of 2 digits followed by a space, followed by 2 digits which are not followed by a word boundary and replace that by the match and a space. If the substitution is successful, repeat until failure.

N.B. This only substitutes after the first field (which could contain spaces). If the first 2 lines are as shown, the range may be dismissed, thus this solution will only specifically alter a line only containing digits after the first field:

```
sed -E ':a;s/, *([0-9]{2} )*[0-9]{2}\B/& /;ta' file
```